# Enable and disable dialog depending on correct input?

Tags: android

This is for a popup button which needs to be disabled if the user clicks submit without entering an input first:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
    .setView(view)
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog,
                final int which) {
            EditText nameEditText = (EditText) view
                    .findViewById(
                            R.id.save_search_dialog_name);
            postToBus(new SaveSearchEvent(
                    nameEditText.getText().toString(),
                    search));
            postToBus(new GoogleAnalyticEvent(
                    GA.CATEGORY_SEARCH_CONTROL,
                    GA.EVENT_SEARCH_SAVE_SEARCH));
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
        //check to see if dialog is empty
        private boolean isEmpty(EditText etText) {
            return etText.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0;
        }
    }
```

I am trying to create a method that will check to ensure my popup dialog cannot be blank. I have a attempted a method isEmpty but and unsure how to use it, or maybe that isn't even the correct approach? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you provide context please? Do you have a button which should be enabled/disabled? In this case case i would suggest using this:

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.your_edit_text_id);
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(s)) { // check whatever you want
            // Disable button or something
        } else {
            // Enable
        }
    } 

});
```